# How to invisible option menu list in action bar?

Tags: android, android-menu, action-menu

I am beginner in Android, I created three menu lists in the action menu. I am not logined-in in the app, but the logout menu is shown. If logged-in the logout menu is visible and the login invisible. If I press logout, the login menu is visible, and the logout menu invisible, please help me?

Comment: Do you know what is your requirement but decide what you want exactly and write it clearly so that other can understand

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuItem item3  = menu.findItem(R.id.ID OF MENU);
        item3.setVisible(false);
    }
```

//  or

//    If you wish to hide ALL menu items, just do:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {

    super.onAttach(activity);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.clear();//This removes all menu items (no need to know the id of each of them)
}
```

Comment: am use main activity & login activity where use this code?, i create all list menus in main activity

Comment: use it in your main activity